# Arithmetic and Assignment operator overloading - return values, scope, combining expressions

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

The code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Dictionary
{
private:
    string dictName;
    struct wordCard
    {
        string word;
        string translation;
    };
    vector<wordCard> Dict;
    bool foundit = false;
public:
    // My attemtp at swap function for copy-and-swap:
    void swap(Dictionary& dict1, Dictionary& dict2)
    {
        Dictionary dict3("tmp");
        dict3.dictName = dict1.dictName;
        dict3.Dict = dict1.Dict;
        dict1.dictName = dict2.dictName;
        dict1.Dict = dict2.Dict;
        dict2.dictName = dict3.dictName;
        dict2.Dict = dict3.Dict;
    }
    // Very basic constructor (setting the dictionary name while creating an object was part of the assignment):
    Dictionary(string name)
    {
        setDictName(name);
    }

    /* various functions that work fine */

    // Overloading "+" operator:
    // The result is supposed to be a new dictionary (without changing the source) where all words from the
    // original dictionaries are present without doubles.
    Dictionary& operator+ (const Dictionary& dict)
    {
        bool doubleword = false;
        string plusname;
        plusname = "Augmenting " + this->dictName + " & " + dict.dictName;
        Dictionary plusDict(plusname);
        plusDict.Dict = this->Dict;
        for (int i = 0; i < dict.Dict.size(); i++)
        {
            doubleword = false;
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < plusDict.Dict.size(); i2++)
            {
                if (plusDict.Dict[i2].word == dict.Dict[i].word)
                {
                    doubleword = true;
                }
            }
            if (!doubleword)
            {
                plusDict.Dict.push_back(dict.Dict[i]);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    /* 2 other overloads that are very similar */

    // Overloading "=" operator (using copy-and-swap):
    // Not part of the assignment, but I couldn't think of another way to make the other operators work.
    Dictionary& operator=(Dictionary dict)
    {
        swap(*this, dict);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And the problems I have with it:

Ideally, it should work like this:

```
Obj1 = result of operation Obj2 + Obj3;
```

What I'm getting at the moment is:

```
Obj1 = Obj2 (ignores Obj3)
```

I have a vague idea why it happens (or, actually, two ideas). First, `operator+` returns `*this`, not the actual result. But when I tried to change it to the temp class object, compiler started screaming at me. Second, I'm aware that I'm using a local variable (temp class object), but I don't know how to make it public so I could use it later. When I try to add a class object to the `public:` section (or `private:`), the compiler treats it as a function declaration, not a class object.

So, how can I either make my temp class object public, or return result of `a+b` instead of `*this`, or make `operator=` catch the result or `operator+` instead of what it returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator +` should return a new object by value and be const - i.e. something like

```
Dictionary operator+ (const Dictionary& dict) const
{
    Dictionary ret;
    //modify ret
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the compiler says `Reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'plusDict' returned`, and then I still get the original class object instead of `plusDict`.

Comment: @user2115087 did you return by reference by any chance?

Comment: Seems like I did. But when I changed `Dictionary&` to `Dictionary` in the `operator+`, it stopped working -- it doesn't show any errors, but I can't even get dictionary name output.

Comment: @user2115087 well, that's the correct thing to do - if it doesn't work, the error is elsewhere. What happens when you step through it with a debugger? Where does it go wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake -- I used another overloaded operator on the test data ^^" It works fine now, thank you.